# Не присваивается значение true для ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Есть 3 кнопки: год, месяц и день. Нужно сделать так, чтобы следующая становилась активной только после того как пользователь выберет значение на предыдущей.
Изначально месяц и день неактивные - с этим проблем не возникло, а вот присвоить значение true не получается.

И MessageBox в конце тоже не появляется.

```
namespace lab4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string a, b, c;
     
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;  

    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            Month.IsEnabled = false;
            Day.IsEnabled = false;
         
        }
        private void Year_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Month_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Year.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                Month.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        private void Day_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Month.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                Day.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            a = Year.Text;
            int year = Int32.Parse(a);
            
            b = Month.Text;
            int month = Int32.Parse(b);
           
            c = Day.Text;
            int day = Int32.Parse(c);

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();

            dt.ToString();

            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(year, month, day);

           if (Day.Text.Length != 0)

           MessageBox.Show("С выбранной даты прошло:\n" + dt2.Subtract(now));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно, покажите XAML. Расскажите, какую именно задачу вы решаете? Для чего это всё? Вот это еще почитайте https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.16.php

Comment: Вам уже говорили, но повторю - вы идете в совершенно неверном направлении, в WPF такой подход не используют, ибо WPF это про привязки и XAML, а с этим всем приходят такие штуки, как команды, которые за вас сделают почти всю работу, даже сами выключат кнопку. Так что, советую подумать, стоит вам сейчас это все делать, или всеж стоит начать разрабатывать проект правильно. Просто как бы, зачем вам WPF тогда, если вы не используете его возможности, берите тогда уж старый добрый WinForms, и то там привязки сейчас в моде.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, надо перенести проверки из месяца в год, из дня в месяц.

```
private void Year_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Year.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                Month.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Ведь разрешить месяц нужно после изменения года.